# Flutter Firebase The method 'data' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, flutter-streambuilder

I'm using Firestore and I tried to get streams by Streambuilder.
However, This error happened.

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object>> 
(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot<Object>, 
AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Object>>>#32fdb):
The method 'data' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: data()
```

And this is my code.

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class UserDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
      String uid;
      UserDetailPage(this.uid);
    
      @override
      _UserDetailPageState createState() => _UserDetailPageState();
    }
    
    class _UserDetailPageState extends State<UserDetailPage> {
      final List<String> datas = <String>['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', '1', '2','3', '4', '5', '6'];
      CollectionReference userstream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
      }
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('User Detail'),
          ),
          body:_buildBody(),
        );
      }
    
     _buildBody() {
    
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: userstream.doc(widget.uid).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            Map<String, dynamic> user_data =snapshot.data.data();
            if(snapshot.hasError){
              return Text('ERROR');
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
    
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: ListView.separated(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                itemCount: 13,
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  return Center(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Text(datas[index]),
                          Text(user_data[datas[index]] is int?user_data[datas[index]].toString():user_data[datas[index]])
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              )
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Interesting thing is that Immediately after this error occurs, the result I wanted appears on the app.
So I thought the problem occurs in initstate() but I dont know exactly what is wrong.

By the way, this Page is called from

```
UserDetailPage( doc.get('uid')!=null?doc.get('uid'):'5AJUsH5LYaQcBiTtO5MA7d6OKx72');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AsyncSnapshot` wraps data that is loaded asynchronously. Calling `snapshot.data` without checking whether the data is available (as you do in the code below), means you are ignoring this fact and might as well not use a `StreamBuilder`:

```
  stream: userstream.doc(widget.uid).snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    Map<String, dynamic> user_data =snapshot.data.data();
```

The proper way to deal with the stream is shown in the FlutterFire documentation on [realtime listeners](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes). The required change for you is that you only call `snapshot.data` *after* all the checks, instead of before them:

```
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasError){
      return Text('ERROR');
    }
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    Map<String, dynamic> user_data =snapshot.data.data();
```